# Connecting 14.04 to LG TV

Tags: 14.04, tv, lg

I just exchanged Windows 7 out for Ubuntu 14.04. Bit of a n00b

I connect my Laptop with a HDMI cable to my LG 42" HD-ready (not full HD) TV, and previously with Windows that always worked fine. So I assume its not a problem with the hardware.

Now I cant seem to get it to work. The TV registers that something is connected to it, but gets no signal. The computer detects the TV as "Goldstar Company Ltd. 72", allows me to mess with its settings but as I say, no setting has worked so that I get an image to my screen.

Would anyone be so kind as to help me out with this?

Comment: Some laptops have a dedicated button for switching to an external display. In my case, it's combined with the F1 key.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should add that I have an PB EasyNote TJ65 machine. Before, on Windows 7, I didn't have to press any button, my display would just turn up on my TV when I turned it on. It runs on a Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4300 @ 2.10GHz × 2 processor, and has a Nvidi gEFORCE g105m - 512mb graphics card.

Comment: Do you use the proprietary Nvidia driver? Check its dual screen setting options.

Comment: Thanks man! 
Being a total noob I wasn’t aware of the driver settings, but had been using by default "X.Org X server - nouveu display driver". Just by trying to switch to the proprietary driver (Nvidia binary driver), which it said was recommended, the problem solved itself. Nice to experience the quick and easy help of the Ubuntu community :)